# A good practice on how to debug a Symfony2 controller

Tags: php, debugging, symfony, controller

I have an Symfony2 project and from time to time, I have PHP errors in my controller.  In order to find out where is the error, I would like to debug the PHP code in the controller.

What do you think is the best practice to debug a controller in Symfony2?

Comment: Cover it with tests applying different test cases, and check coverage - you'll find weak places.

Comment: Could you be more precize please? What kind of tests? How to display those tests? var_dump does not work!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error page tells you many usefull things:

- The error **message** - What is exactly going wrong? (and something: how can I solve this?)
- The **line number** - On which line in the controller are things going wrong?
- The **exception** name - Hover over the name to see the fully qualified namespace. It tells you on which component something is going wrong.
- The **trace** - You can see a full trace path which tells you much usefull things: On which class/method is the exception thrown? Which methods are executed first?

---

Another good practise is to create tests for your controller, both functional and unit tests. Learn more about them in [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html).

---

If you need more help, it is better to specify what error you get.

Comment: thank you Wouter J. You are talking about the developent interface error page? For example, in eclipse the Error Log ???

Comment: You should always develop in a dev environment (with the `app_dev.php` front controller). It will show you a nice error page which includes the things I said. It looks something like: http://www.ens.ro/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/Screenshot-at-2012-04-07-122445.png

Comment: Oh, yes, of course, I am developping in the dev environement but the problem is that I am using ajax and it is not displaying the errors.

Comment: Go to the page you requested with AJAX and see the error yourself.